# Using DVD ISOs with Rolling Releases

Tags: apt, kali-linux, rolling-release

I'm using Kali Linux for pentesting exercises.  Often I find that I need to install a small utility from the repositories.   Because Kali is a rolling release, and I'm not updating the OS regularly, this can mean a major update to every component of the OS when installing a minor tool.

To get around this in other distributions, I've used DVD releases to keep my OS consistent to be installed from and updated by a single source.

I'm trying this with Kali and I'm stuck in a loop...

```
apt-cdrom add
```

All good, running update

```
apt update

E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2019.2 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20190508-10:56] kali-last-snapshot Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

vi /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb [trusted=yes] ...
```

Then update again

```
apt update

E: Failed to fetch cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2019.2 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20190508-10:56]/dists/kali-last-snapshot/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
```

Removing the CD lines from /etc/apt.d/sources.list and trying again takes me down the same path.

Does anyone know why it would to accept the CDROM as an apt source or how to troubleshoot this further?

(Of course this is not for production systems or real-world exercises.)

Comment: You can make a [persistent live USB pendrive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) from the Kali iso file and add the small utilities that you need: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install utility1 utility2`. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/minp/details#Kali_Linux_2019.3).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, but it only led to another problem and maybe the answer.

The "failed to fetch" error shows it trying to reach an i386 repo, which is wrong as the distro is amd64.

Adding [arch=amd64] to the sources.list entry for the repository fixed the errors.

However...

There are almost no debs on the Kali ISOs...   The distro is packaged as a live CD with a sources.list pointing to the rolling release.  There doesn't appear to be any repository snapshot of the time of the build, anywhere.  Even the liveCD contains a cramfs filesystem with a complete OS, but even *it* doesn't have debs.

I didn't realize the depth of "rolling releases" for Kali.  I glossed over it as a minor issue when they did it a few years back:

https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-rolling-edition-2016-1/

https://www.zdnet.com/article/linux-distributions-rolling-releases-versus-point-releases-which-should-you-choose/

```
You might want to choose a point-release distribution if you fit these
statements:
...
- You prioritize stability above new look/feel/functionality 
- You want a minimum of distraction/disturbance from update installation
```

This means that when I install new packages, either I:

- update the entire distro regularly
- risk having packages which were tested against Dec 2019 installed on a system from May 2019

I guess I'll just keep backups, snapshots and use a lot of --dry-run on apt.